# Is there a way to include Template Role Name in Connect Events

Tags: docusignapi

For DocuSign, we have an account that is integrated and we use the connect events to store information about the envelope in the DB and then into our reporting repository. For every envelope we send, we apply a matching template. Is there a way to get Template Role Name included in the connect events that are pushed to us?

Answer (score 0):

The Connect event payload doesn't have the role name as an option.

But you can call the [EnvelopeRecipients::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list) API method with the envelopeId from the event payload.

You'll receive back data for all of the envelope's recipients including their role name. Example response:

```
{
   agents: [],
   carbonCopies: [
      {
         email: "larry@example.com",
         name: "Larry Kluger",
         note: "",
         recipientId: "2",
         recipientIdGuid: "a31eaf15-48bb-4a40-a8a7-cf28325f1d78",
         requireIdLookup: "false",
         roleName: "cc",  //   <<===
         routingOrder: "2",
         status: "created",
         userId: "00db048f-1dbc-489f-935a-c2d7bc178ca1"
      }
   ],
   certifiedDeliveries: [],
   currentRoutingOrder: "1",
   editors: [],
   inPersonSigners: [],
   intermediaries: [],
   recipientCount: "2",
   seals: [],
   signers: [
      {
         creationReason: "sender",
         deliveryMethod: "email",
         email: "Pat.Edwards@example.com",
         isBulkRecipient: "false",
         name: "Pat Edwards",
         note: "",
         recipientId: "1",
         recipientIdGuid: "f21e3531-277a-4ee1-912b-1d359d342fa7",
         requireIdLookup: "false",
         roleName: "signer",  //   <<===
         routingOrder: "1",
         status: "sent",
         userId: "69e573ac-d2e2-41d0-9ad3-b5e64317942f"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Larry mentioned we do not send roleName in Connect response, but there is a diff workaround to accomplish this if you are using API to send an envelope. While creating an envelope, you can pass Recipient Level Custom Fields in the envelope creation call, in this Recipient Level Custom Field you can pass the roleName as a String. In Connect Response you will receive this Custom Field for each recipient, this can be used to interpret the roleName which was used to create an envelope.

If recipient part of API call looks like below where `Signer1` is the roleName which you have used but passed it as recipient level custom field:

```
"recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "email": "docusign.sso+internal22@gmail.com",
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "roleName": "Signer1",
                        "routingOrder": "1",
                        "customFields":[
                            "Signer1"
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
```

then Connect Response will look like:

```
<RecipientStatus>
        <Type>Signer</Type>
        <Email>johndoeemail@gmail.com</Email>
        <UserName>John Doe</UserName>
        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
        <Sent>2019-03-07T12:14:48.38</Sent>
        <Status>Sent</Status>
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField>Signer1</CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
</RecipientStatus>
```